# Signaling without a persistent connection

Tags: webrtc

Curious if anyone is aware of technology that can fill the role of signaling without having a persistent connection to every device (i.e. an open socket).

Better yet, is anyone aware of any apps that actively do this today?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some signalling (chat) protocols like XMPP have transports like [BOSH](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html) that are non-persistent in the sense that they use HTTP long polling.

If you want to get even less persistent the typical approach is to use push notifications to summon the user and then answer the call once the user establishes a more persistent connection in response to the push

Comment: Is push notifications typically how WhatsApp starts its sessions? I'll have to look how they work behind the scenes, but I assumed GCM would also keep an active connection. But I guess that's if you're working with Android Phones. iOS similarly.

Comment: all push notification things are effectively using a persistent connections, yes (based on xmpp sometimes). However, they don't require the app and bundle messages for multiple apps which makes them more efficient. Most importantly, the OS vendors have no interest in killing these processes ;-)